# Config files are already in remote git repository. Want to unversion but not delete. How?

Tags: git, version-control, github

My friend and I have elected to use git and GitHub to collaborate on a project. We are both very new to it.

My friend made an initial commit of our project files with his version of the project's config files included in it. My config files will be different. We do not want to send changes to these files back and forth.

I have already issued `git init` and `git pull git@github.com:my_friend/our_repository.git master` to get our project files onto my development server.

I then created a `.gitignore` file in the project root on my dev server (where I did `git init`):

```
# this is .gitignore in the project's root directory
index.php
config/some_config_file.php
config/another_config_file.php
```

Since these config files are already in the repository, these lines in `.gitignore` aren't going to do anything. I understand this. Other SO answers have suggested these commands:

```
git rm --cached index.php
git rm --cached config/some_config_file.php
git rm --cached config/another_config_file.php
git commit -m "hope this works"
git push
```

*but* this deleted these files in the remote GitHub repository! Not good. I want these files to remain on GitHub so it doesn't alarm my friend. **I just want to keep my own unversioned copies of the files on my dev server, independent of whatever is going on in the GitHub repository.**

How can I achieve this setup with git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that, but you could tell git to ignore further (local) changes to those files. Try:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <your_file>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked beautifully. Btw, after some more googling, I found that `git ls-files -v | grep ^[a-z]` will show you which files have been set this way. More info here, including two aliases for `~/.gitconfig`: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html

Comment: The `--assumed-unchanged` technique is a good one as long as you are aware of the gotchas such as when switching branches & merging commits where the file in question has changed (see docs).

Comment: @Sri: very valid point! Whenever you update the local repo with the upstream version, and that file was changed, you'll have to deal with it manually. This might be annoying if the files in question are frequently changed.

Answer (score 3):

GitHub only stores what's actually in the repo. You can't delete files from the repo but also leave them in the repo.

The best solution is to let your colleagues know that the files have been removed, so they can keep their own copies intact and just copy them back into their working tree (since they'll now be ignored) after pulling your changes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I think `--assume-unchanged` is what I am looking for.